# Dynamically add labels and textboxes on the basis of datagridview WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

im new to WPF
Actually I created an XML Editor where it will browse an xml file and load it elements data into datagrid view like this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmHcv.png)

but when i double clicked on any row in data grid it need to dynamically populate labels and textboxes with its values like this
Capture.PNG[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtExo.png)

Help me through this

Comment: You can ask specific questions here about a precisely described particular problem. But this is not a training board. Can you show us a concrete problem in your code?

Answer (score -1):

In order to dynamically fill a textblock or a label on a double click of a datagrid, you can :
-First add the event to your datagrid in the xaml:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="datagrid" MouseDoubleClick="datagrid_MouseDoubleClick"></DataGrid>
```

-Then retrieve the data in the event in order to display them in the label or textblock :

```
        private void datagrid_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            YourClass SelectedItem = (YourClass)datagrid.SelectedItem;
            if(SelectedItem != null)
            {
                textblock1.Text = SelectedItem.name;
                textblock2.Text = SelectedItem.id.ToString();
                label1.Text = SelectedItem.branch;
            }
        }
```